# Smart compare of JSON files - covering all attributes and differences

Tags: java, json

I need to compare 2 JSON files in Java. The files can contain any information: numbers, string, XML / HTML elements etc'.

In one file I have this data:

```
          "text": "\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-amount\u0027 role\u003d\u0027text\u0027 aria-label\u003d\u00271,496 undefineds\u0027\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-currency\u0027\u003e₪\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-minus-sign\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-int-num\u0027\u003e1,496\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-decimals-dot\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-decimals\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"
```

While on the other file I have this information:

```
      "text": "\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-amount\u0027 role\u003d\u0027text\u0027 aria-label\u003d\u00271,496 ₪\u0027\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-currency\u0027\u003e₪\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-minus-sign\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-int-num\u0027\u003e1,496\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-decimals-dot\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class\u003d\u0027per-decimals\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"
```

I base my JSON compare on package org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.

My code:

```
 JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(expectedJson.toString(), actualJson.toString(), JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
```

I'm showing the result text in an HTML report so my out put was:

?1,496 (expected)

?1,496 (actual)

My code couldn't show me the "real" difference which is the 'aria-label' attribute in the 2 JSONs. Is there a why to show the difference in an elegant manner?

Comment: Tal, what would you like to achieve? To get some map, keys representing the labels with the difference and the values the actual different values?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Yes, I wish to see everything.